# Matrix representation of Maschke's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know Maschke's Theorem in the following form:

Let $\ G$ be a finite group over $\ F$ and let $\ V$ be an $\ FG$-module.
If $\ U$ is an $\ FG$-submodule of $\ V$, then there is an $\ FG$-submodule $\ W$ of $\ V$
such that
$\ V=U \bigoplus\ W$.

**The matrix equivalent is stated as follows:**

Suppose that $\phi$ is a reducible representation
of a finite group G over F of degree n. Then we know that $\phi$ is
equivalent to a representation of the form \begin{align*}g \rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
X_g & 0 \\
Y_g & Z_g
\end{pmatrix}, g\in\ G\end{align*}for some matrices $\ X_g$,$\ Y_g$ and $\ Z_g$  and $\ X_g$ is a $\ k * k$ matrix  for $\ 0<k<n$.

*Maschke's Theorem asserts further that $\phi$ is equivalent to a representation of the form \begin{align*}g \rightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
A_g & 0 \\
0 & B_g
\end{pmatrix}, g\in\ G\end{align*}where $\ A_g$ is $\ k * k$ and $\ 0<k<n$.*

**What I do not understand is the above italicized portion.**

P.S. I have borrowed the material from the book *Representations and Characters of Groups by GORDON JAMES and MARTIN LIEBECK, chapter 8 page 73-74*

Comment: What is $k{}{}{}{}?$

Comment: 1) That is a matrix representaion *with respect to a basis that is gotten as a union of a basis of $U$ and a basis of $w$.* 2) You need $|G|\cdot1\neq0_F$ for Maschke's theorem to hold.

Comment: Doesn't this just mean that $G$ has a $k$ dimensional representation $g \rightarrow A_g$ over $U$ and a representation $g \rightarrow B_g$ over $W$ with dimension $\dim(V)-k$ ?

Answer (score 1):

As a commenter said, this is just the matrix with respect to some matrix. Note that an $\Bbb F$ representation of a group $G$ is equivalent to either of the following:

- An $\Bbb F G$-module $V$
- A linear map $\Bbb FG\to \operatorname{End}(V)$

By Maschke's theorem, $\Bbb F G$ is semisimple whenever $\operatorname{char}\Bbb F$ does not divide $|G|$. In particular, if $\Bbb F$ has characteristic $0$ (for example $\Bbb C$), then $\Bbb F G$ is semisimple for any finite group. Thus, the regular module $\Bbb F G$ can be written as a direct sum of matrix rings over a division ring. Further, any finitely generated $\Bbb FG$-module can be written in terms of these summands (since we know what the possible simple modules are, and any finitely generated module decomposes into a direct sum of simple modules).

Now using your decomposition, choose a basis for $U$ and a basis for $V$, and its fairly easy to see that this direct sum of two matrix rings is equivalent to the form you provided.